# CentOS entered emergency mode after reboot

Tags: centos, lvm

Please help me, this is very very important.

I have a CentOS server running properly for a month. It was installed with LVM.

Today I found that I could not connect to the MongoDB and failed to restart the service. In addition, when I type `su root` to switch user, I waited for a long time but it didn't ask for my password. I tried to copy the mongodb log to my home directory but it said `error reading 'mongod.log': Input/output error`

So I decided to reboot the server to see if it may help.

Then the server automatically entered the emergency mode:
[image]

Then I tried these commands to see what happened:
[image]

Does it mean that my SSD (WD SN750) is dead? The server functioned properly four days ago and before I reboot I still can do some IO operations in other folders. However, it can just enter emergency mode now....

How can I fix this? There are important data about my working paper on it.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from any rescue media (Live CD/PXE/whatever) and run and post the result of:

`smartctl -A /dev/sda`

Consult with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T. for the attributes which might be failing. Normally the most important is: Reallocated Sectors Count (must be relatively low).

Then you can mount your old filesystem somewhere e.g. `/mnt/system` and inspect your logs. I presume you have at least CentOS 7 which uses `journald`, so depending on whether your drive is SATA or NVME you could simply check if there are any I/O errors by running:

```
journald -D /mnt/system/var/log/journald | egrep 'sd|nvme'
```

I would **not** recommend running `badblocks` if your disk is indeed failing because doing so may damage even more data. First try to use `ddrescue` to retrieve the data, then do anything else.

Comment: I turn on my server today and everything just works fine. I have no idea. Could you provide some possible causes for this situation? BTW, the SMART information about RSC is ` 5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0`

Comment: Post the complete `smartctl -a /dev/device` output after running `smartctl -t long /dev/device`